# Open Shell/CMD in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I would like to open a standard windows cmd using `CreateProcessA(NULL, "cmd", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);`

When executing the program, the console flashes briefly and then disappears
How do I open the command line programmatically and leave it open for the user to enter arbitrary commands?

Comment: Not sure what is going on without the full code, but if that is the only thing you have in your code, then the process will terminate immediately after executing it, thus killing all children processes.

add a loop after the command or even better some sort of handler like "WaitForSingleObject"

Comment: @Makaronodentro: *"thus killing all children processes"* - No, that's not what's happening. What is happening is, that the system closes the process (and thread) handle returned from `CreateProcessW` when the process terminates. And since those were the last open handles to the *cmd.exe* process, that process gets closed. The child/parent relationship is not at all interesting (and while maintained in Windows, it isn't used for anything useful anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `/k` option of `cmd.exe`, which keeps the console window open for user entry. The following snippet opens a new shell console and waits for the user to exit it using the `exit` command:

```
STARTUPINFOA si;   
ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
char cmd_exe[32767];
GetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC", cmd_exe, 32767);
if (CreateProcessA(cmd_exe, "/k", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    std::cout << "cmd process exit code = " << dwExitCode << std::endl;
}
else
{
    DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    std::cout << "cmd process not started, error = " << dwErrorCode << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The location of the Windows folder is user-defined during installation, so you should use `GetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC")` to get the correct path to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Removed folder name, assuming `cmd.exe` is in the PATH.

Comment: see my comment to Bruno's answer about that issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : I did not know the path was not searched when using CreateProcess. Thanks for pointing this out. Answer edited.

Answer (score -1):

This is code that opens and waits for the process state to be changed:

```
if (CreateProcessA(NULL, "cmd.exe",
    NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL,
    NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
}
else
{
    // Failed to launch ...
}
```

Comment: Downvoting. This answer only shows how to wait for the cmd window to close, but does not do anything to address the OP's question of how to stop the cmd window from closing as soon as it opens.  Also, if you don't specify a full path to `cmd.exe`, `CreateProcess()` is not likely to find it: "*In the case of a partial name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the specification. **The function will not use the search path**.*"